# How do can search a scalar variable for a pattern and add something before and after match?

Tags: regex, perl

Here is my scalar:

```
my $var = "foo1";
```

and here is what I tried to do:

```
$var =~ s/[0-9]/_[0-9]/;
```

Result:

```
foo_[0-9]
```

Expected Result:

```
foo_1
```

It would be great if you could answer for finding `foo` and adding the underscore after the match, and also finding `1` and adding the underscore before.

```
$var = s/foo/something/
```

and

```
$var = s/[0-9]/something/
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capture what you want to insert, then insert what you captured:

```
s/([0-9])/_$1/;
```

Or use a lookahead:

```
s/(?=[0-9])/_/;
```

As requested, solutions that also match `foo`:

```
s/(foo)([0-9])/$1_$2/;

s/foo\K([0-9])/_$1/;

s/foo\K(?=[0-9])/_/;
```

Note that captures slow down the match.

Comment: You might need something like `\b` before `foo` unless you're ok with matching `doofoo`.

Comment: Wow, I never knew about `\K`! Thanks! You learn something new every day.

Comment: @Joel Berger, New since 5.10.